# Is the "Divisions" feature available inside Force.com Embedded apps?

Tags: force.com-embedded

I've been looking into Salesforce's "Divisions" functionality for a Force.com Embedded app that I'm currently building.

I'd like to know if the following things are possible.

1. Enable and configure Divisions inside of a Partner Developer Edition org. I've found contradictory indications with the Salesforce docs as to whether or not this is even possible. [This page says NO](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000175929&language=en_US), while [these](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_division.htm&language=en_US) [pages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=overview_of_divisions.htm&language=en_US) seem to [say YES.](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_and_editing_divisions.htm&language=en_US)
2. Have the Division-based customizations propagate to a customer's org once they purchase a subscription to my app.

Not worried at this point if implementing Divisions is the *right* solution. Just wondering if it's a *possible* solution.  ;-)

Thanks!